# Android YouTube player - how do I get the list of videos in a channel and choose one to play?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am looking at the sample applications download for YouTube API from here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

But there does not seem to be an example of how to display the videos of a channel and choose one to be displayed.

EDIT:
I entered this url into my browser:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=my_real_key&channelId=UCoLEarNS6E-Kbzoya_p7k2Q&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
```

But I got this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to look at the [`YouTube Data API`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). You will find there documentation about how the API can be accessed. You can also find [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries).

You could also make the requests yourself. Here is an example URL that retrieves the latest videos from a channel :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20"
```

After that you will receive a `JSON` with video ids and details, and you can construct your video url like this :

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id_here}
```

Comment: thank you. By the way, I am trying to play this channel. http://www.youtube.com/user/g33ktalktv - is the last part of the url the channel id? Or how would I locate the channel id for it? When I try to use this channel id in the url you provided, it gave me a 403 error - not configured.

Comment: that is the username. I think you can change the query to pass in username instead of channelId

Comment: I just updated my original question with the error I got. Would you know why it happens? I did get the Android key during the configuration.

Comment: what did you use as `API_KEY`? Did you create a project here https://code.google.com/apis/console ?

Comment: also make sure to enable YoutubeData API in the project. your request works with my key.

Comment: yes I did both of those things. I am wondering if the problem is that I enter the url from the browser. Could that be the issue?

Comment: it works from my browser. depends on your key... maybe that is the problem. create a browser key for making requests from browser maybe..

Comment: Ah yes, with the browser key it worked. So does that mean I can only make the request with the Android key in the Android apps?

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu, I am facing this issue in using Android Key. Any Help will be really appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950504/youtube-get-uploaded-video-list-filenotfound-error

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to read about and use YouTube Data API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java?hl=pl

It allows such behaviour.